# Learning SQL Server v18 (Management Studio) at home without a server

Tags: sql-server

I have installed the software but am at home and so do not have a server to connect to. How can I get around this to take the classes?

Comment: You can't run SQL queries without an instance to connect to. There is no magic word around for that.

Comment: You don't need a "server" machine or LAN to use SQL Server. You will need to install a SQL Server instance on your home PC.

Comment: You can install *SQL Server Developer* or *SQL Server Express*, both are free, see here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: You can also use [localdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5612/getting-started-with-sql-server-2017-express-localdb/) or a [container](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Learn-How-to-Deploy-SQL-Server-2019-in-Containers-in-Just-Minutes).

Comment: You can also use online services like https://www.db-fiddle.com/ or http://sqlfiddle.com/ for testing & learning processes.

Answer (score 4):

You can install SQL Server Developer Edition on the same computer as SQL Server Management Studio.  The free download is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).

Comment: Thanks David. Can you point me in the right direction to get all of this working? I have not used this before and am taking classes for a new job. I've installed Developer - which installed another iteration of SQL Server (in addition to Management Studio). Once it installed it went to a command prompt screen. Ugghh.